# iOS Basics: private property, public setter/getter

Tags: ios, objective-c, model

I've been reading the tutorials and I'm right now designing the model's architecture, and since I'm new to `Objective-C`, I'm not sure if the standards are like `Java` where you have **public setter/getter and private attribute**. This is 1 question I'd like to ask.

If the standards are so, declaring private properties are done in the `*.m` file `@interface`, but how do I `@syntetize` a **setter/getter** and how do I call them from outside: is it like `[object SetProperty:property] ?`

If the standards are different, can I get an example of a model class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this link. its awesome to understand this basic thing. http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties

Answer (score 3):

A property is essentially a promise that a class provides certain accessor methods. For example:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) Foo *foo;
```

is a promise that the class provides `-foo` and `-setFoo:` methods. So, if you want the accessors to be public, declare the property in your class's public interface (i.e. in the header file) and be done with it.

It's true that the instance variable that backs that property (`_foo`, unless you specify a different name) will then be accessible, but it's very poor form to access another object's instance variables directly. Many things in Objective-C are governed by convention and that's generally enough to avoid problems. Also, a given property doesn't *have* to be backed by any instance variable at all: a property like `fullName` might be computed from other properties like `firstName` and `lastName`, so there's good reason beyond mere convention for clients to avoid accessing ivars directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a private property and create public setter/getter method of your own. From this method you can assign or retrieve the value back.

```
@interface Person : NSObject
-(void)setTheName:(NSString *)fullName;
-(NSString *)theName;
@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "Person.h"

@interface Person()
@property(atomic) NSString *fullName;
@end

@implementation Person

-(void)setTheName:(NSString *)fullName{
    self.fullName = fullName;
}

-(NSString *)theName{
    return self.fullName;
}

@end
```

In the above is private however you can check the selector still exists(but throws a warning)

```
if ([p respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullName:)]) {
    [p performSelector:@selector(setFullName:) withObject:@"Anoop"];
}
NSLog(@">>>> %@",[p theName]);
```

Output will be :

> ```
>  >>>> Anoop
> ```

---

**However it is seldom required to set any private property from outside. If that is the requirement we can make the property public.**

Comment: is this the standard way to write Objective-C code?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco no see Caleb's answer or mine.

Comment: What's the point of doing this compared to putting the `@property` declaration in the interface?

Comment: @Caleb: Just for showing that it is possible but not a good/conventional way of doing.

Answer (score 1):

The common approach if you want to give access to your attribute is to use the keyword `@property` in the .h file of your class to define a property. This will automatically define a setter and a getter and you don't need to synthesise your property as of Xcode 4.4.

Your private attribute will be accessible within your .m file and will have the name of your property with "_" as a prefix by default.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is true that Objective-C uses another terminology than most of the other languages like Java. If I get what you're asking, if you want a property to be directly available outside the class, the property must be declared in the .h file. However if you want to hide the implementation of your code, you can declare a property in the .m file and provide setters/getters to the outside world just returning the information you want to be visible.

The @synthesize clause is to me a simpifier. By synthesizing a property the getter/setter will be automatically implemented and you don't need to do it yourself.

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: You don't need `@synthesize` anymore, as that's the default for properties.

Comment: yes, this answer my question. Now, is it standard for model classes to declare properties on .h since implementation will probably be `return property` ?

Comment: Yes that's standard. I only declare properties in the m file when i don't want other classes to acces them or when I want to hide the implementation of what's going on in the back.

Comment: @Caleb Synthesize isn't required anymore ?

Comment: Nope, `@synthesize` has been the default for properties for almost a year now. It doesn't hurt anything, of course, and you might still use it if you want to specify the name of the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that declaring a property causes the compiler to create accessor for you . so if i require a pseudo private property personally I declare it in the implementation, if i need pseudo public property i declare it in the header. public getter / private setter can be handled as indicated below. There is no need to create your own setters and getters  prefer using an attribute as it saves writing setters/getters ;

in the header (.h)

```
  @interface Person : NSObject
     @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *fullName;
  @end
```

in the implementation file (.m)

```
#import "Person.h"

@interface Person()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *fullName;
@end

@implementation Person

 ... whatever this class does
```

// self.fullName = @"John Doe";

```
@end
```